# Gunicorn access to other workers memory

Tags: python, gunicorn

Currently I've got a trading bot application which has a UI interface to start and stop currently running bots. In behind there is also a bot manager, which **keeps track of all running bots and has the ability to start and stop** them. Each bot is started in its own thread and the manager must have access to thats thread memory (in order to stop it when necessary). Currently If i specify more workers then depending which worker the request lands on I've no access to the thread I need.

At this moment, I've got a gunicorn setup in docker:

```
gunicorn app:application --worker-tmp-dir /dev/shm --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --timeout 600 --workers 1 --threads 4
```

The problem:

Yesterday one of the bots stopped because apparently gunicorn ran out of memory and the worker had to restart in the process killing running bot. (Can't have that). These bots should be able to run for months if needed. Is there a way to fix or tell gunicorn to never stop workers or processes? Or maybe I should use a different python server like **waitress or uWSGI**?